# Have two lists blist with values and alist with indexes how do i change the value of Alist to 0 based on the index position given in Blist in pytho?

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
alist = [8,7,4,2]
blist = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

how do I replace the values in blist with the value 0 for the list of indexes given in alist?

```
for i,j in enumerate(blist):
     if i==alist:
          blist[alist] == 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

many problems: that's alist you want to loop, `==` only makes tests, you can't use a list as an index in regular python (blist[alist])

```
alist = [8,7,4,2]
blist = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

for index in alist:
    blist[index] = 0
    
print(blist)
>>> [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```